# Scrape data in script tag

Tags: javascript, python, selenium-webdriver, scrape

Could anybody suggest a way to scrape the data in a `<script>` tag, specifically, in this case the 30-min table from AEMO (https://www.aemo.com.au/aemo/apps/visualisations/elec-nem-priceanddemand.html).

To get the data table, I will need to click either the button to show the table on the website or the download button. However, the hindrance here is that the button and the text for the table are hidden behind the `<script>` tag when I tried to scrape it using Selenium.

Here is my code so far:

```
# import libraries
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
import time
import pandas as pd
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

url = "https://www.aemo.com.au/aemo/apps/visualisations/elec-nem-priceanddemand.html"
browser = webdriver.Safari(executable_path='/usr/bin/safaridriver')
browser.get(url)
try:
    print(browser.page_source)
except:
    print("not found")
finally:
    browser.quit()
```

and part of the result is:

```
<body aurelia-app="visualisation-main" data-gr-c-s-loaded="true">
    <div class="splash">
      <div class="message"><span class="icon-spinner"></span></div>
    </div>

    <script src="jspm_packages/system.js"></script>
    <script src="config.js"></script>
    <script>
      System.import('aurelia-bootstrapper');
    </script>


</body></html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Selenium has its own way to locate elements, such as [find_element_by_css_selector](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html). And often times, browsers need some time to render elements, so you might need to use [WebdriverWait](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html).

Here is an example to extract the spot price from the page:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

url = 'https://www.aemo.com.au/aemo/apps/visualisations/elec-nem-priceanddemand.html'

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get(url)

sel = 'body > div > compose > div > compose.fill-height.flex-container.au-target > compose > div > div:nth-child(1) > div'
element = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, sel))
)

print(element.text)
```

The result

```
$92.02/MWh
```